# Receiving error from firebase facebook login: "undefined in property email"

Tags: firebase

I'm authenticating with firebase through the facebook authentication and it keeps returning:

```
Uncaught Error: transaction failed: Data returned contains undefined in property email
```

A week or so ago this was worked fine.  What's strange is with my personal account if I try to authenticate a second time in a row then it will work.  However, I created some test accounts on facebook through the developer dashboard and those accounts always return this error after logging in with the facebook auth screen.

Any help is much appreciated as the code seems to fail in the firebase.js file so I have no way to debug it.

Comment: Engineer at Firebase here. Could you post the snippet of code that you're using to authenticate, and save your user data in Firebase? Feel free to ping me directly (rob@firebase.com) if you prefer.

Comment: I apologize I have resolved the issue.  I was looking for user.email from the facebook response when it should have been facebook.emails where emails is an array.  Sorry for the premature post.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize I have resolved the issue. I was looking for user.email from the facebook response when it should have been user.emails where emails is an array. Sorry for the premature post. – Trout